# Bad configuration option: \240\240user when setting up Amazon CodeCommit

Tags: ssh, aws-codecommit

When cloning a repo, I get this error message

`/c/Users/username/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: \240\240user
/c/Users/username/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: \240\240identityfile`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you paste the same config file in from the documentation, it uses character 240 instead of a normal space.

To fix, delete the leading spaces before each indented line and replace with normal spaces.

If on Windows, use Notepad++ so that you can specify Linux line endings.

Comment: For Unix-like systems (e.g., Linux, macOS, BSD), you can use the `sed` command to replace character 240 (non-breaking space) with normal spaces in the config file:

`sed 's/\xC2\xA0/ /g' input_config_file > output_config_file`

Comment: I literally deleted the spaces and put a tab and it worked. Thanks a lot