# "Unable to negotiate" with AWS CodeCommit: "no matching host key type found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to connect to AWS CodeCommit with SSH. I've followed every step in this guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-windows.html#setting-up-ssh-windows-install-git

but when I get to where I need to run the following command

```
ssh MY-SSH-KEY@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

I get this error

> Unable to negotiate with 52.95.17.51 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa

Comment: What is the output of `ssh -Q key`?

Answer (score 25):

Nvm i found a solution i had to add this to my .ssh/config file

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

if you getting this error after you added those two lines

Bad configuration option: \240\240pubkeyacceptedkeytypes

is because the spaces in the config file arent spaces their 240 characters

this helped me

[Bad configuration option: \240\240user when setting up Amazon CodeCommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467278/bad-configuration-option-240-240user-when-setting-up-amazon-codecommit)

what i did was copy the spaces that were on my other lines and used them in the new lines i added

Comment: Small clarification: the content that Austin Grant shows is in fact in two lines, Line 1: `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`, and line 2: `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa`

Comment: @coderazzi thank you. I now corrected the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Further clarification - those two lines should go within the specific config you set up to connect to AWS code commit. It is possible to have multiple `Host` entries in the config file and you need to ensure you're putting it under the CodeCommit `Host`. It would be useful to demonstrate this in the answer, with a fuller sample of the surrounding context including an additional host (different to AWS CodeCommit).

Comment: On my case the setup was exactly as (aws 2022 june) describes https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html . Adding these two lines helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that windows was referring to the wrong root hard drive disk. *(because pc managed by system administrators)*

The solution was to create a new environment variable called `HOME`. With the directory of your .ssh folder.

- press windows key
- write edit environment

[image]

- Click on the first new button

[image]

- variable name = HOME
- variable value = directory of your `.ssh` folder

[image]

- press ok
- press the other ok to save the changes.
- Apply @Austin Grant answer afterwards if it doesn't work.